# Ruby - How to check if a string contains all the words in an array?

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array of strings:
`phrases = ["Have a good Thanksgiving", "Eat lots of food"]`

I have another array of single words:  `words = ["eat", "food"]`

I want to return the entries in the first array if the string contains all the words in the second array.

So, it should look something like this:
`phrases.select{ |x| x.include_all?(words) }`

Should I just create the `include_all?` function to iterate through each member of the `words` array and do the comparison, or is there any built-in methods I'm missing?

Comment: what about partial mathcing? ie word="eat" phrases = ["I don't like meat"]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're actually very close to the solution.

```
phrases.select do |phrase|
  words.all?{ |word| phrase.include? word }
end
```

The `all?` method is on `Enumerable`, and returns true if the block evaluates to true for each item in the collection.

Depending on exactly what your definition of the phrase "including" the word is, you may want to define your own `include_all?` method, or a method on `String` to determine the match. The `include?` method is case-sensitive and doesn't care about word boundaries. If those aren't your requirements, you can use a Regexp in place of `include?` or define your own method to wrap that logic up.

Comment: That works, thanks.  I just called `upcase` on the fields being compared to ensure that case was not an issue.